# Dynamic Form in ASP.NET MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a small problem.
I want to have dropdown list with some objects. After clicking on one I want to add it to list with textfield for naming it. I don't want to limit quantity of this fields. I want to receive in controller ID (stored in dropdown list) and name (given by user) for each selected item. How can I do it?
I was thinking about storing it in some fields as a text, and parsing in cotroller but I think it's not elegant.

EDIT.
Ok, Thansk for your help, but it's not working for me correctly.
I generate html like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="96" name="Inputs[0].Key">
<input type="text" name="Inputs[0].Value">
```

In my controller I'm receiving this dictionary. The problem is that quantity of elements is correct, but all values are null. What is wrong here?

Comment: Answer for your edit: If you're using exactly the code you posted, you are missing close tags for input. You should do like this: `<input type="hidden" value="96" name="Inputs[0].Key" />` or this `<input type="hidden" value="96" name="Inputs[0].Key"></input>`

Answer (score 1):

Use `IEnumerable<KeyPairValue<string,string>> MySelectedItem = new List<KeyPairValue<string,string>>();` on model, and when adding it to the list, name it like an array:

```
MySelectedItem[1].Key, MySelectedItem[1].Value, MySelectedItem[2].Key...
```

(I haven't tested this, but it should work)

Edit: check out this blog post with better explanation on how to do it: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: Answer for your edit: If you're using exactly the code you posted, you are missing close tags for input. You should do like this: `<input type="hidden" value="96" name="Inputs[0].Key" />` or this `<input type="hidden" value="96" name="Inputs[0].Key"></input>`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about this is by using array-style model binding.

So, for each element you wish to name you create a hidden field to store the drop down value plus a text field to store the user-given name. You name them as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="element[0].Key" /><input type="text" name="name[0].Value" />
```

increasing the index value each time. This is easily achieved with a bit of JavaScript. You then create an action method which takes a `KeyValuePair<string, string>[]` as a parameter. You will then be able to parse through your values no problem with a loop or LINQ expression.